# Nuxjs Main Route with optional parameter

Tags: nuxt.js

**Nuxtjs project Root route (/)** has optional parameter as named type, but without this parameter, I will get *"This page could not be found"* and *"Page not run"*.

> `main route component is: _type.vue`
>   and in *mysite.com* i will get this error message *"This page could not be found"* 
>   But when I call it by parameter every thing is good!

Such as this: *mysite.com/plane*

Comment: Your link does nothing.

Comment: this is an example link not real.

Comment: Could you add some code to help explain your issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

Make sure there isn't `index.vue` file inside `pages` folder.

Inside `pages` folder create a folder named `_type` (or any other variable parameter name).

Then inside that folder create `index.vue` and put your code there.